# Display flex in Chrome with 100% height of child elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a flex layout in follwing fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TfB9c/14/

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-frame">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="inner-tile ">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="inner-tile ">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="inner-tile ">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="inner-tile ">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="inner-tile ">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-frame {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tile {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #15b575;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 1px inset white;
}
.inner-tile {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In Firefox, i get the expected result, in one row, each tiles height is equal:

[image: Firefox]

In Chrome this is not the case. What is the error, I can't figure it out?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make some modifications and specify `display: flex` on the parent `.tile` and `flex: 1` to child `.inner-tile`

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3gpnynL/)

Comment: Seriously I can't thank you enough. This was driving me crazy. I you ever stay in Freiburg, Germany, leave a message and you'll get some ice cold beers! Have a great day!